# How can I find the center of ellipse given an Arc and ellipse radii?

Tags: geometry

I have an arc with start and end points and also I have width and height of the ellipse. Using these can I find center of the ellipse?

hi Stefan,

how can i calculate $(x,y)$ center , can u give idea?

Comment: Is this about implementation in Mathematica? What do you mean by "I have arc"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

If you only have the start and end point, you can only solve for two parameters ($x$ and $y$ of your center). If you know the alignment of your ellipse, this is enough and can be calculated by solving the equation system given from the equation of the ellipse and your points.

If the ellipse is rotated, you also need the rotation angle $\alpha$ and thus a third point from your arc.

Comment: hi Stefan,


how can i calculate (x,y) center , can u give idea?

Comment: @SushmithaSush You should look at the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53093/how-to-find-the-center-of-an-ellipse) shown in the "duplicate question"-part of your question. The main idea is to take the ellipse equation ($(x-x_0)^2/a^2+(y-y0)^2/b^2=r^2$) and put your known points and lengths in. This should give you the center $(x_0,y_0)$.